# I need to set active profile in spring boot app though maven command but its taking default profile

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I have 3 environments in my application i.e dev, prod, test i for that i separate files like `application-prod.yml,application-dev.yml,applicaton-test.yml` and also `application.properties` i am running command -> `mvn spring-boot:run -Dspring.profiles.active=prod` but its taking profile as a default profile

### application.properties

server.port=8002

```
application-prod.yml
--------------------------
spring:
  jpa:
    show-sql: true
    properties:
      hibernate: dialect:org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
      ddl-auto: update

  datasource:
    username: scott
    password: tiger
    url: jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe
    driver-class-name: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver

  app:
    message : This for DevEnvironment connect to Oracle

logging:
  level:
    org:
      springframework:
        web: DEBUG
```

Comment: which version are you using? Let me know if below helps

Comment: for V1 you are supposed to run -  mvn spring-boot:run -Dspring.profiles.active=prod
and for V2.X: mvn spring-boot:run -Dspring-boot.run.profiles=prod

Answer (score 0):

If you are using maven command then try the following to set the profile :

```
mvn spring-boot:run -Dspring-boot.run.profiles=foo,bar
```

The above command sets the run time spring profile through the maven plugin.
Official [doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin/examples/run-profiles.html).

Comment: or without maven : `java  -jar  -Dspring.profiles.active=prod  yorapp.jar`